# ¿Es correcto usar "aperturar" como sinónimo de "abrir"?

Tags: verbos, diferencias-regionales, sinónimos, hispanoamérica

Leía ayer [en Twitter](https://twitter.com/AsambleaVE/status/886542513171025920):

> #16J 07:00am Comienzan a **aperturarse** los puntos soberanos en todo el país para que ciudadanos manifiesten su voluntad. #HoyElPuebloDecide

Lo que la Asamblea Nacional de Venezuela quería decir es que comenzaban a **abrirse** unos puntos de votación.

Como hablante de castellano de España, este uso me pareció muy raro y así me lo confirmó que no aparezca en el DLE. Sin embargo, para mi sorpresa el Diccionario de americanismos sí lo recoge:

> [**aperturar**](http://lema.rae.es/damer/srv/search?id=njyu4sGxUx0A6ha5vp5).
>   I.  1.  tr. Ho, Ve, Pe, Bo. Inaugurar alguien algo. pop + cult → espon.

Y veo que efectivamente cada vez se usa más en detrimento de "inaugurar", como se ve [en Google Trends](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?date=all&q=aperturar,inaugurar):

[image]

Sin embargo, ¿se puede usar como sinónimo de *abrir*?

Comment: Es el mismo mecanismo que en *recepcionar* (que significa "recibir" sólo que parece que se diera más aires), pero es la primera vez que lo escucho.

Comment: A mi me suenan terrible _aperturar y recepcionar_. No se porque la gente elige formas más difíciles cuando son mas fáciles y cortas _abrir y recibir_. ¿será para parecer más inteligentes? ;-)

Comment: Yo estoy *ambicionando* una respuesta que nos saque de dudas :)

Comment: @DGaleano La lengua no se guía por esos criterios de economía. A veces sí es necesario complicar la cosa; por ejemplo, *traicionar* es derivado de *traición* y quizá sonó raro al comienzo, pero la alternativa era que "traicionar" se dijese *traer* (una homonimia bastante molesta). Entiendo *recepcionar* como "pasar por una oficina o proceso formal de recepción", más detallado que *recibir*, pero igual me suena mal...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No, no es correcto.**

Se pronunció Fundéu en [*abrir*, mejor que *aperturar*](http://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/abrir-mejor-que-aperturar-944/):

> Abrir, mejor que aperturar, es el verbo relacionado con el sustantivo apertura.
>
> En los medios de comunicación está muy extendido el verbo aperturar: «Firman el contrato para aperturar la calle que da acceso a la Urbanización García Guillén», «Más de 600 mujeres en este municipio de Tierra Caliente necesitan recursos para aperturar o ampliar un negocio» o «Desde que el Grupo Dolle comenzó a aperturar tiendas de moda en el año 2014, su crecimiento se ha incrementado de forma notoria».
>
> Tal como indica el Diccionario panhispánico de dudas, **el uso de [*aperturar*](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=EGIh7gTdAD6LGcbSxq), especialmente habitual en el lenguaje bancario, no está justificado**. Del mismo modo, el diccionario Clave señala que la utilización de aperturar es innecesaria.
>
> Así pues, en los ejemplos iniciales habría sido preferible escribir «Firman el contrato para construir la calle que da acceso a la Urbanización García Guillén», «Más de 600 mujeres en este municipio de Tierra Caliente necesitan recursos para abrir o ampliar un negocio» o «Desde que el Grupo Dolle comenzó a abrir/inaugurar tiendas de moda en el año 2014, su crecimiento se ha incrementado de forma notoria».

El enlace interno nos lleva al Diccionario panhispánico de dudas:

> [**apertura**](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=EGIh7gTdAD6LGcbSxq)
>
> 2. A partir del sustantivo apertura (‘acción de abrir’), se ha formado el verbo aperturar, que ha empezado a utilizarse en los últimos años como equivalente de abrir: «Ordeno que esos contenedores sean aperturados y revisados» (DHoy [Ec.] 8.7.97); «Ayer domingo la Cooperativa Agraria de Producción Casa Grande aperturó sus Terceros Juegos de Verano» (Comercio [Perú] 14.1.75). Es especialmente frecuente en el lenguaje bancario, donde se ha puesto de moda la expresión aperturar una cuenta, en lugar de abrir una cuenta. **Su uso no está justificado y debe evitarse.**

Finalmente leo en Diccionario de dudas el artículo [*Aperturar o abrir*](https://www.diccionariodedudas.com/aperturar-o-abrir/):

> La palabra correcta es abrir. No es apropiado emplear el término aperturar como equivalente del verbo abrir.
>
> El verbo abrir se refiere a la acción de ‘descubrir o destapar algo que estaba oculto’, ‘iniciar una actividad’, ‘hacer algo patente o manifiesto’, ‘separar lo que estaba junto’, entre otras cosas.
>
> Como tal, aperturar es un verbo que deriva de la voz sustantiva apertura, que significa ‘acción de abrir’. Coloquialmente, la palabra ha venido imponiéndose en el lenguaje, sobre todo en el ámbito bancario, para hacer referencia al ‘acto de hacer apertura de una cuenta bancaria’, y de allí se ha ido extendiendo a otros ámbitos.